# SurfaceView Thread Fails

Tags: java, android, debugging, surfaceview

The thread in the surface view class that has the canvas keeps on crashing the program because the thread got into a fatal exception. Then the NullPointerException comes. It says the problem occurs on line 28, but everything there is fine. Then the program skips hundreds of frames.It says the application is doing too much work in the main thread. Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
package com.mtprogramming.blockfight;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

SurfaceHolder sviewholder;
Thread thread = null;
Boolean game = true;
public SView(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    sviewholder = getHolder();
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(game){
        if(sviewholder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }
        Canvas sview = sviewholder.lockCanvas();
        sview.drawRGB(33, 66, 150);
        sviewholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(sview);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the reference of the holder you are getting is Null, because the SurfaceHolder has not even being created by the time you are using it, do not call getHolder from onCreate, in stead, implement the SurfaceHolder callbacks and start the thread after surface has been created and once you have a real reference to the Surfaceholder...

Regards!

Comment: Can you give an example?